# Quarkus - ContextNotActiveException when injecting a request scoped bean in Interceptor

Tags: java, quarkus, interceptor, requesthandler, requestscope

I've got a Quarkus application. The entry point to trigger this application is a class which implements AWS RequestHandler.
Before it runs I would like to set the context depending on the given parameter fields. To store the context somewhere I created a requestScoped bean with a field that we set with a simple setter method.

To do this I thought of using Interceptors. In my interceptor class, I inject this request scoped bean.

When running the application it triggers the interceptor but I noticed I get an error while debugging.

**Method threw 'javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException'. Cannot evaluate common.service.MyRequestScopedBean_ClientProxy.toString()**

I've run this in another application where I trigger a rest endpoint instead. And don't have the same issue.

Quarkus platform version: 2.7.5.Final.

Why is **ContextNotActiveException** being thrown here, is there a way to fix this?

```
@Setter
@Getter
@RequestScoped
public class MyRequestScopedBean {

    private String context;
}
```

My InterceptorBinding annotation:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContextBinding {
}
```

The ContextInterceptor class:

```
@Slf4j
@Interceptor
@ContextBinding
public class ContextInterceptor {

    @Inject
    MyRequestScopedBean myRequestScopedBean;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object setContext(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

        log.info("{}", context);

        myRequestScopedBean.setContext("Some context");

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

My handler class, with @AcitivateRequestContext:

```
@Slf4j
@ActivateRequestContext
@ContextBinding
@Named("Handler")
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Event, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(Event event, Context context) {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interceptor does not declare a `@Priority`. By specification, such interceptor should not be enabled, but Quarkus deviates from that and assigns a default priority of `0`. You should even see this warning:

```
The interceptor x.y.z.ContextInterceptor does not declare any @Priority.
It will be assigned a default priority value of 0.
```

The `@ActivateRequestContext` interceptor has, by specification, the priority of `PLATFORM_BEFORE + 100`.

Combined, this means that your interceptor runs *before* the request context is activated. You should assign your interceptor a correct priority explicitly:

```java
@Interceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.LIBRARY_BEFORE + 100)
@ContextBinding
public class ContextInterceptor {
    ...
}
```

I chose `LIBRARY_BEFORE + 100` with little deliberation, but it seems likely to me that your interceptor priority should be in the "early interceptors defined by extension libraries" category, so `LIBRARY_BEFORE + 100` should be a good start.

Comment: Thank you! So basically because interceptors have a priority value which is lower then the `@AcitivateRequestContext` it runs before the request scoped bean can be activated. So to make sure the request scoped bean is activated first we want our Interceptor's priority value to be higher so that it gets invoked later.

Correct me if I'm wrong please :)

Comment: Beans are not activated, but contexts are. Request scoped beans exist in a request context, so the request context must be active before you attempt to call any method on a request scoped bean. `@ActivateRequestContext` is an interceptor binding for a built in interceptor that activates the request context for the duration of `context.proceed()`. You just need to order the interceptors properly, which is what `@Priority` does.